# How to access mapping table from code first c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, many-to-many, code-first

```
 private void ManyToMany_ProductLines_L4(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductLine>()
                .HasMany(l => l.L4)
                .WithMany(p => p.ProductLine)
                .Map(
                  m =>
                  {
                      m.MapLeftKey("ProductLinesID");
                      m.MapRightKey("L4ID");
                      m.ToTable("ProductLinesL4");
                  });
        }

  public class ProductLine
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual List<L4> L4 { get; set; }
    }

public class L4
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ProductLine> ProductLine { get; set; }
    }
```

I have many to many relationship and I want to access this table ProductLinesL4 , but for this table I don`t have a Model in project.Is have the way to access this table or I need to create a Model?

Comment: I am not sure, but isn't this table accessible via your context?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create a model for it if you want to have direct access to the table in the context.

If you need to do "something" on that table, you can choose to manually manage the many-to-many relationship; if you need to do so (for example you need to create many-to-many-to-many) probably you will need to create a PK to on that table too.

Hope it helps :)